# Can't get past American Megatrends screen on boot

Tags: boot, keyboard, bios

[image]
When I boot up my computer, this shows up. I cannot input with the keyboard at all and have tried USB keyboards and a USB to PS/2 adapter, nothing has worked. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your going to have to install a compatible processor in order to update the firmware in order to use the processor you want to use

Comment: My friend gave me a mobo and processor, he confirmed that it works

Comment: does the numlock or caps lock lights come on when you hit numlock/capslock?

Comment: Nope, no lights on the keyboard come on.